# CSS Rotated text not displaying corretly

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

**CSS**

```
.a4{
    height:297mm;
    width:210mm;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.left{
    height:297mm;
    width:15mm;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
    overflow:none;
    position:absolute;
}

.left_text{
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    writing-mode: lr-tb;
    color:white;
    font-size:40pt;
}
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div class="a4">
<div class="left">
        <span class="left_text"><?php echo $brand." snapshot survey"?></span>
</div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/5QL62/1/

The issue I have is that cannot see the rotated text.  I had assumed (clearly incorrectly) that the text would simply be within the `.left' div running bottom to top.

Any advice, feedback and solutions as to where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: for one, your fiddle is trying to echo php. replace that with text and you will see your text rotated. Now, as for how it is to be displayed, you may want to look into transform-origin to tell it to rotate by the bottom left. see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: The reason you cannot see the rotated text is, you have the text inside php tags , and jsfiddle automatically comments out your text .

Comment: If you want the text to fit inside the div, you can increase the width of the span element and position it inside the div

Comment: Hi all, appreciate the feedback.  Having replaced the php with text and adding in transform origin, still no joy.

Comment: See updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5QL62/1/

Comment: if your positions are fixed , this will work: http://jsfiddle.net/5QL62/6/

Comment: @adirohan - I need the text aligned to the bottom of the blue column - whilst your code has the text within the column it isn't aligned to the bottom.

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5QL62/7/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with property "horizontal-bt". This will solves your problem. `Check link here` `http://jsfiddle.net/5QL62/9/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in jsfiddle

```
       <div class="a4">
      <div class="left">
      <span class="left_text">snapshot survey</span>
      </div>
      </div>
```

And your css will remain same

Comment: The issue I am having is that even when that is changed, how do I get the text to appear at the bottom of the left div running bottom to top.  See the updated JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks but that is not correct.  The text needs to be aligned to the bottom of the `'left` div and the text needs to run from the bottom to the top.

Comment: The text needs to be within the blue column on the left, not outside and then it needs to be aligned to the bottom of that same blue column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57222/discussion-between-praveen-and-homer-j).